# Only keep recent emails in claws mail (or any light weight mail client)

Tags: software-recommendation, lubuntu, claws, email-client

Since I'm using a netbook with only 16GB SSD, I want to use most lightweight client possible (hence not Thunderbird)

However, I wasn't able to find an option to download only recent mails, say, more recent than a week, in claws mail.

Is there a way to turn this on? If claws mail does not have it, does any lightweight mail client have it? On a related note, how may I see the space that all my mails are occupying?

Answer (score 1):

[Geary](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Geary) is a lightweight mail client for GNOME 3. It only downloads recent email by default. This can be configured [in the Accounts dialog](http://yorba.org/geary/help/accounts.html).

In any case, [Postler](https://launchpad.net/postler) was definitely taking this approach, but it was discontinued (and officially suggesting Geary instead).

Answer (score 1):

Claws Mail won't download all msg bodies automatically (depending on the settings you choose), so this shouldn't be a problem. If the msg cache is getting too big, use 'discard folder cache' from the Folder Properties.